# Java TimerTask Strange Behaviour

Tags: java, timer, schedule

I have a custom Timer Task that executes once after X seconds in a controller... The scenario which I encountered yesterday happens when I schedule my Timer Task and, instantly, I schedule another time and a third time. Every time I schedule, I create a custom object from a class A and assign it to this timer task (so that it does some work in the run method afterwards).

The strange scenario comes when the custom timer task is executed because itś like I have assigned the third object to the three custom timer task object... Instead of retaining each custom timer task object its corresponding instance of A... I will investigate meanwhile the API...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "execute", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public void executeTimerTask(@RequestParam("task") String task) {

      new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("task: " + task);
          }
       }, 10 * 1000);
}
```

This would be more or less a copy of what I have before creating the custom timer task... If I execute quickly and hit this endpoint three times (before 10 seconds), when the timer task is executed what it's going to be printed is the value from the third endpoint execution. What I want is a way of retaining each value when the task is executed...

Comment: Please show us your code, your intended behaviour and what you are experiencing instead. Just taking turns guessing, without seeing anything, won't get anyone far. Also "I will investigate meanwhile the API" is what you should have done **before** asking the question here.

Comment: I know my friend... But I cant show the code... unless I made some slightly changes... Wait a minute...

Comment: I have investigated a LOT in my work and I am not the kind of guy the looses his hope... But I decided to ask for help... Anyway I will keep on inbvestigating... That's what I did but wasnt successfull...

Comment: Your current setup looks fine. You should provide us a minimal code of yours so we  can investigate the issue. Can strip lots of detail if you want to keeps in private, but the class being used, the way you used should be demonstrated in your code